# How to do the model binding of deep objects from open-api doc in asp.net core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, swagger, openapi

How to binding deep objects existing in the open API documentation in asp.net core 3.1 ?

The request I am trying to parse is:

```
GET https://localhost:5001/Product/?product[name]=mac&product[type]=computer
```

See below the controller as well as the product model

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class DevicesController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery]ProductQuery productQuery)
    {
        var response = await _mediator.Send(productQuery);
        return Ok(response);
    }

}


public class ProductQuery: IRequest<IEnumerable<ProductDto>>
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public string Type {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: To this endpoint, the URL looks `https://.../Product?name=mac&type=computer`.

Comment: @vernou this is deepObject see Query Parameters here https://swagger.io/docs/specification/serialization/

Comment: Maybe this can help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59926069/swagger-generates-incorrect-url-for-dictionary-in-asp-core-3

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Core does not support binding to query string parameters defined in that way out-of-the-box. You will have to write a custom model binder to achieve this.